# Getting error while printing hello world in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am making simple hello world in spring using MVC taking help from this site 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

But I am getting error .

Here is my file :
web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

}
```

I download the code with above url and run

**http://*******:8080/Spring3MVC/hello**
**http://*******:8080/Spring3MVC/index**
**http://*******:8080/Spring3MVC/hello.jsp** in all i am getting this error

getting error 
**he requested resource (/Spring3MVC) is not available.**

Answer (score 0):

First, you're making a request to

```
/Spring3MVC
```

(assuming `/Spring3MVC` is your context path), whil your `@Controller` handler method is mapped to

```
/Spring3MVC/hello
```

Second, your `@Controller` isn't being registered. For that to happen, you need to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your `spring-servlet.xml` context configuration while also adding the `mvc` namespace to your namespace declarations.

Start by reading the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), however long it is.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not 
  bound.

Comment: @user Did you add the namespace declaration like I told you? No, you didn't. I can't type right now but you can find it online.

Comment: Not getting please help :(

Comment: @user I'm on my phone :( Find a better Spring MVC tutorial and copy the XML header that contains an XML namespace for `mvc`.

Comment: hi please check my update ..i solve the error but didn't display text..:(

Comment: any idea of this problem

Comment: @user944513 Change your `servlet-mapping` `url-pattern` to `/*`, but otherwise, `/Spring3MVC/hello` should be the right URL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45862/discussion-between-user944513-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher servlet is mapping all * urls, and your endpoint uses /hello url, so try:
`http://***:8080/Spring3MVC/hello` or
`http://***:8080/hello` depending on your application server context settings

Also please add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your context configuration to "turn-on" `@Contoller` annotation